# How to select specified columns from a table

Tags: sql, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I created a table with timestamp, symbol, askPrice1,askPrice2, AskQty1,AskQty2 ...
and we will need to output to the following cols,

```py
select askPrice1*askQty1, askPrice2*askQty2 ... askPrice50*askQty50 from table
```

Is there any inbuilt functions we can use and what is the optimal way to calculate on dolphinDB?

thanks!

Comment: That's why you should store things vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns in the select statement, the example code is as follows:

```py
select askPrice1 *askQty1, askPrice2*askQty2 ... askPrice50*askQty50 from table. This is the optimal way.
```